# How to get current moving speed of the box2d object

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I apply force to the b2body, but would like to know is there a way to know what speed the b2body is after applyforce/applylinearimpulse?

```
b2Body* car;
b2Vec2 force = b2Vec2(0,100);
car->ApplyForce(force, car->GetPosition());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

b2Vec2 vel = body->GetLinearVelocity();

Answer (score -1):

After apply force to the center of mass:

`v = F * t / m`. F - force, m - body mass, t - apply time. I think it will give good approximation if no damping is used.

I'm not so sure about impulse. But, `imp = m * v` So by applying linear impulse to the center of mass you get `imp/bodyMass` velocity increment

Comment: there's no way to retrieve this value from the b2body?